# Flask: Caching static files (.js, .css)

Tags: python, caching, flask

I really could not find any resource on this. So how can I seperate caching of views/functions than static files (i.e. .css,.js)? 
I want to cache my static objects for a week, on the other hand I need to cache functions/views for only a few minutes.

When I do following

```
from flask.ext.cache import Cache
cache = Cache(config={'CACHE_TYPE': 'simple'})
cache.init_app(app)

@cache.cached(timeout=500)
def index():

    return render_template('index.html')
```

then all views, objects' cache time is set to the same value, 500. How to go about it?

Answer (score 2):

I would not server the static files from my python application but try to delegate that to the web server (nginx, apache... ). 
Then you could set the time to expire through headers controlling how long should the browser cache them.

Comment: OK, lets say flask trying to set the cache 500 for static objects (well it caches all kinds of things or none), ang apache tries to set 1 week. Which would have preference? The static files would be cached for 500 or 1 week?

Comment: If your http server is serving the static files, Flask doesn't. That means Flask won't cache them at all.

Comment: I agree to the comment above. Plus you do not need to necessarily cache them because they will not overload your application server. The files will be served directly from the disk by the web server.